# C# - Cannot get value from DataTable

Tags: c#, button, datatable

I'm making an app in windows Form, and I need to write in buttons from a datatable. The datatable gets data from database. However, when data are in the datatable, I cannot get it to insert into the buttons.

So far, Here's my code:

```
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id_produto, designacao FROM produtos ORDER BY id_categoria ASC;", mConn);
        MySqlDataAdapter dacom = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
        mConn.Open();
        dacom.Fill(dtprodutos);
        numprodutos = dtprodutos.Rows.Count;

        foreach (DataRow row in dtprodutos.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
        {
            string id_produto = row["id_produto"].ToString();
            string designacao = row["designacao"].ToString();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numprodutos; i++)
        {
            buttonList[i].Text = designacao[i];//Not working. I don't know if it's right.
            buttonList[i].Show();
        }
```

"dtprodutos" is my DataTable and "buttonList" is a list with the buttons I want to insert text to.

I don't know if, to do what I want, I need this foreach. And I don't know either if what I wrote in the first line of the last FOR is right.

I appreciate any suggestions and help.

If you have any questions, ask me.

Comment: Do you have a connection string added to the command?

Comment: Yes. It already works! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var i = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in dtprodutos.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
{
    buttonList[i++].Text = row["designacao"].ToString();
}
```